# Laravel php get last element in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5

I have the following json file with products details:

```
  "products": [
    {
      "sku": 123,
      "name": "iphone 7",
      "categoryPath": [
        {
          "id": "abcat0800000",
          "name": "Cell Phones"
        },
        {

          "id": "pcmcat209400050001",
          "name": "All Cell Phones with Plans"

        }
      ],
}
]
```

I would like only to store the last value (ID and NAME) of the categoryPath Array:

> ```
>           "id": "pcmcat209400050001",
>           "name": "All Cell Phones with Plans"
> ```

My current code takes the json file, decode the json and insert in products table the information.

```
    $json = File::get("/json/cell-0.json");
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $array1 = (array)$data;
    //table products
    foreach ($array1['products'] as $obj) {
        DB::table('products')->insert(array(
            'productSku' => ((isset($obj->sku) ? $obj->sku : 1)),
            'productName' => ((isset($obj->name) ? $obj->name : null)),
            'categoryId' => end($obj->categoryPath->id),
            'categoryName' => end($obj->categoryPath->name)
        ));
```

Taking into consideration that array->categoryPath have multiple fields I would like to use a function (eg: end()) in order to take id and name only of the last values.

Using end($obj->categoryPath->id) I receive the following error ->

> Attempt to modify property of non-object

Is this the best way to retrieve the last value of a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use end() probably but your accessors would have to be outside the end() call (untested):

```
    foreach ($array1['products'] as $obj) {

    DB::table('products')->insert(array(
        'productSku' => ((isset($obj->sku) ? $obj->sku : 1)),
        'productName' => ((isset($obj->name) ? $obj->name : null)),
        'categoryId' => end($obj->categoryPath)->id,
        'categoryName' => end($obj->categoryPath)->name
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're getting the last element is incorrect, here is the refactored code. I also eliminated the need to cast data as an array as well.

```
$json = File::get("/json/cell-0.json");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
//table products
foreach ($data['products'] as $product) {
    $lastCategory = isset($product['categoryPath']) && $size = sizeof($product['categoryPath']) ? $product['categoryPath'][$size-1] : array('id' => null, 'name' => null);
    DB::table('products')->insert(
        array(
            'productSku' => isset($product['sku']) ? $product['sku'] : 1,
            'productName' => isset($product['name']) ? $product['name'] : null,
            'categoryId' => lastCategory['id'],
            'categoryName' => lastCategory['name']
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried the example. $size is not detected in the second part of $lastCategory. the other option was simpler. thank you so much @Augwa